# props.isSameUser is not a function inside the renderBubble function

Tags: react-native-gifted-chat

Trying to render a custom name above the chatBubble.
I am getting props.isSameUser not a function inside the renderBubble function. Which contradicts what others have been getting. I am not sure if its typed out properly but it shouldn't matter. Another issue is that when I render the text it gets rendered in the center and I cannot find any way to align it properly.

```
renderBubble = (props: Readonly<AvatarProps<IMessage>>) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          {!props.isSameUser(props.currentMessage, props.previousMessage) &&
            props.currentMessage.user.name}
        </Text>
        <Bubble
          {...props}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
    <GiftedChat
      renderBubble={this.renderBubble}
    />
```

some examples where it works:

https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/pull/448#issuecomment-451661928

[image: chat image with wrong username position]